# Azure VM IIS HTTP Status Codes Changed

Tags: asp.net, azure, virtual-machine, http-status-codes, iis-10

I have a couple Azure VMs behind a Basic Load Balancer with an HTTP URL Health Probe for the Backend Pool.  To mark a server down, that URL returns Status Code 503 (Service Unavailable), but when I call that page from those VMs, the Status Code returned is 403.  That still has the desired effect, I suppose, of marking the server down - but I dont understand why the code I set has changed.

This is from an ASP.NET web forms application on the VMs.  I look at developer tools in the browser, and from my local machine or from a Dev server on our local network, that page returns Status Code 503, but calling that page from the VMs in Azure, the Status Code is 403.

Here's where I set the Status Code in that page:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.StatusCode = 503
Response.Flush()
```

I suppose I should mention that my local is a Windows 10 box, and the server VM is Windows Server 2016.  Both are running IIS 10.  The application is compiled with .NET Framework 4.6.

Here's the dev tools from my localhost:
[image: dev tools from localhost]

Here's the dev tools from the server in azure:
[image: dev tools from prod vm in azure]

Why the change?  Anything I can do to stop this behavior?

Comment: Please dig further with failed request tracing, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Once you can rule out any interference from IIS modules, it would be solely the issues of your web apps.

Comment: `but calling that page from the VMs in Azure, the Status Code is 403.` In this case, do you call it via load balancer public IP or DNS name?

Comment: I typically call it using the FQDN of the server.  Using the Private IP address of the server gives the same result.  If I use the Public IP, I get a response from the other server in the Load Balancer.  Since I'm getting a 403, the Health Probe correctly fails and the Load Balancer routes requests to the other server.  I just dont understand why I set a 503, and it is returned as 403.

Answer (score 0):

So today I tried enabling Failed Request Tracing, but either something wasnt set up correctly, or the error was being handled elsewhere, and didnt result in any failed requests being logged.
Since I wasnt getting any failed requests logged, I opened up Process Monitor and could see that immediately after the call to my Health Probe page, I was getting a call to my custom HTTP Error page.  That page must have been what was giving the 403 (dont know why, b/c that page works correctly for other HTTP Errors with a friendly error message and logging of the error to my custom error tracking solution).

I was going to change the Status Code to see if there was something special with the 503 that I was setting that was handled differently in IIS, but that got me thinking about how I was setting the status code...
In my research today, I saw this page https://www.leansentry.com/HowTo/AspNet-Response-Flush-Poor-Performance which cautions against using `Response.Flush()`.  The code that I had implemented was in the `Page_PreRender` method, so there's not really a need to Flush there anyway.
**I removed the Response.Flush and of course, my troubles went away.**

The Health Probe page no longer triggers an Error from the Azure VM, and therefore, the status code that I get in my client browser is the 503 that I set in code.

So I guess this case is closed.  I will need to figure out why the HTTP Error page was throwing a 403 instead of returning the friendly error message, but that should be easy enough...